# Error during SSL installation cPanel/WHM

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a dedicated server and I am using the install wizard via WHM to install an SSL certificate.

I have the following keys:

- Certificate key
- RSA private key
- CA certificate

I paste these three elements into the wizard along with the domain, IP address and username but I get this error:

```
SSL install aborted due to error: Unable to save certificate key.
Certificate verification passed
```

Have I missed a step?

I have given it another go to make sure I am copying and pasting the info correctly and I am now getting the following error:

> SSL install aborted due to error:
>   Sorry, you must have a dedicated ip to
>   use this feature for the user:
>   username! If you are intending to
>   install a shared certificate you must
>   use the username "nobody" for security
>   and bandwidth reporting reasons.

Even though I am using a dedicated IP address,  I am getting this problem.

I thought I would also add that this SSL certificate has been installed on a shared hosting environment with my previous hostig provider.  The account with them is still active, however the domain and its contents now reside on the dedicated server - could this cause problems?

Answer (score 2):

The installation was failing because I let WHM read the certificate and prefill the user details.  The 'user' field needs to be nobody if the server you're installing on only has one IP address.  Once I had set the user to be 'nobody', the certificate could then be installed.